# Find eligible words in a game of Scrabble based on first and last characters

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I was looking at various problems associated with game of Scrabble. I came across this problem "Find eligible words in a game of Scrabble based on first  and last characters in optimal time." If i use trie DS i can get all words starting with specific character and compare last character of each of those words with given last character. But in that case i am not using information that it is ending with specific character in building DS and in using it brut force way. Is there any better way to organize such that in place of walking all words starting with first characters, i can use that information that it is ending with given last characters.

Comment: Make one parse of the dictionary and make a 26 * 26 array of lists for each combination of first and last letters. Of course this is only efficient if you want to search for more than one case.

Comment: is for C or C++ ?

Comment: Either of c/c++ is fine.